# Making a flex item float right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="float:right"> Ignore parent? </div>
    <div> another child </div>
</div>
```

The parent has

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
}
```

For my first child, I want to simply float the item to the right.

And my other divs to follow the flex rule set by the parent.

Is this something possible?

If not, how do I do a `float: right` under flex?

Comment: NOTE: Generally in SO, and not just those here, flexbox answers works for the OP cases b/c `float` is often misused for [its very purpose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float). But indeed, `float` with `flexbox`/`order` don't work together, and one would have to use some HTML reordering, and in the most common use cases, media queries for `float` or `flex`+ aletered `order` depending of the screen width (for example)

Answer (score 434, accepted):

You can't use `float` inside **flex container** and the reason is that **float property does not apply to flex-level boxes** as you can see here [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/272/).

So if you want to position `child` element to right of `parent` element you can use `margin-left: auto` but now `child` element will also push other `div` to the right as you can see here [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/273/).

What you can do now is change order of elements and set `order: 2` on `child` element so it doesn't affect second div

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  margin-left: auto;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Ignore parent?</div>
  <div>another child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks i can take a look at the first solution. I don't want to use display:absolute as my other children shouldn't be covered under the first child.

Comment: "*floats do not intrude into the flex container*". That's true, but it is not the reason. The reason is that `float` property does not apply to flex-level boxes.

Comment: This works, thank you! Why does `justify-self: end;` (or something similar) not work for the child? This seems like a not-so-flexy solution to a flexbox problem.

Comment: @BradyDowling I know this is a late reply, but justify-self end requires the display to be set to a grid. Flexboxes will ignore justify-self:end. See here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self

Comment: <div>another child</div>
 <div class="child">Ignore parent?</div>
U can swap the two div and without the order 2 it works too

Answer (score 47):

You don't need floats. In fact, they're useless because [floats are ignored in flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-flexbox-1-20160301/#flex-containers).

You also don't need CSS positioning.

There are several flex methods available. [**`auto`** margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) have been mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36182782/3597276).

Here are two other options:

- Use `justify-content: space-between` and the `order` property.
- Use `justify-content: space-between` and reverse the order of the divs.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.parent:first-of-type > div:last-child { order: -1; }

p { background-color: #ddd;}
```

```html
<p>Method 1: Use <code>justify-content: space-between</code> and <code>order-1</code></p>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="float:right"> Ignore parent? </div>
    <div>another child </div>
</div>

<hr>

<p>Method 2: Use <code>justify-content: space-between</code> and reverse the order of 
             divs in the mark-up</p>

<div class="parent">
    <div>another child </div>
    <div class="child" style="float:right"> Ignore parent? </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24):

Use `justify-content: flex-end;` in parent:

```
display: flex;
width: 100%;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

Comment: `justify-content: flex-end` with put BOTH flex items to the right.

Comment: ok but what if i what to make one element at right and one in left

Comment: @scriptydude hello, you can do: justify-content: space-around;

Answer (score 2):

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post

Comment: If you follow the question from the beginning, you should understand the OP is trying to make flex object be at left and right side. Is there need for me to be explaining 'justify-content: space between' ?

Comment: Well, yes, there is. Especially when you answer very old questions. There is already an answer using `space-between`. Since you add another one, you are supposed to explain why your way of doing is different, and even better, than the already existing upvoted answers. The fact that you, now, tell me that `space-between` is the core of your answer reinforce my wondering "how this is different than other answers using `space-between`".

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not tracking "code-only" answers for fun. I don't really care for that question to be frank. But your answer was automatically flagged "low quality" by the system (and I suppose by some users, but I don't know exactly what trigger an answer to be in the "low quality" list). I am required, when reviewing the "low quality" queue to take action. Either edit the answer myself (which I am unable. I am not a pro of CSS, but I do use it from times to times, and yet, I am unable to explain the difference between your answer and others. One extra proof that this ...

Comment: ... explanation has to come from you, and is not purely redundant), or to add that canned comment about necessity of an explanation (or to recommend deletion, which is not fitted here, since your answer is obviously an honest attempt to bring clarity... but explanation in addition to code are required)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I tried space-around and it works fine by given spaces between each item, but what I actually want was to have the last item at the right side, so the items can occupy the whole width, so I just feels like putting it here for someone might be looking for something similar. Not a big fan of answering questions here. I will try and be putting explanation next time, thanks