# pull-right / float-right not working in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can I make [bootstrap-tabdrop.js](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-tabdrop/) compatible with Bootstrap 4?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/testone/ag4sa7fr/1/)

I changed `pull-right` to `float-right` but did not work :(

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182635/making-a-flex-item-float-right) float right / left not works in flex item you need to change the order of item and put the `margin-left:auto`

```
li.tabdrop{
    order:2;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ag4sa7fr/2/

Comment: thanks, Can you check why `dropdown-toggle` does not hide/unhide?

Comment: check this https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment