# How can I align two parts at the left and right in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm implementing navigation bar of github and wanna align two parts at the left and right. Therefore, I used `float` property, but it didn't work for my code. What is wrong with me?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.navigation__left {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}

.navigation__right {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: right;
}

.navigation__left,
.navigation__right {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navigation__left img {
  height: 4vh;
}

.navigation__left__dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

.navigation__left:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.navigation__left:nth-child(even):hover .navigation__left__dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navigation__right:last-child a {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0.5vw 1vw 0.5vw 1vw;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

input {
  height: 3vh;
  width: 15vw;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3%;
  padding: 10px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="https://github.com">
          <img src="github.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Why Github?</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Enterprise</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Marketplace</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search GitHub">
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <a href="#">Sign In</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[JSFIDDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/harambae/7Lyr39v1/)

Comment: See [float does not work in a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194630/float-does-not-work-in-a-flex-container) and [Making a flex item float right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182635/making-a-flex-item-float-right/36182782).

Comment: See [Using auto margins for main axis alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#Using_auto_margins_for_main_axis_alignment).

Comment: @showdev Then, do I have to wrap `navigation__right` with container to use auto margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox ignores floats.
Instead, use `margin` to separate the left navigation items from the right navigation items.

> A common pattern is a navigation bar where some key items are aligned to the right, with the main group on the left.
>
> Auto margins will take up all of the space that they can in their axis — it is how centering a block with margin auto left and right works.
>
> [Using auto margins for main axis alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#Using_auto_margins_for_main_axis_alignment)

Consider using the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to target the first `navigation__right` element that follows a `navigation__left` element, and setting `margin-left:auto`.

```
.navigation__left + .navigation__right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Demonstration:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.navigation__left {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.navigation__left,
.navigation__right {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navigation__right {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.navigation__left+.navigation__right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navigation__left img {
  height: 4vh;
}

.navigation__left__dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

.navigation__left:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.navigation__left:nth-child(even):hover .navigation__left__dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navigation__right:last-child a {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0.5vw 1vw 0.5vw 1vw;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

input {
  height: 3vh;
  width: 15vw;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3%;
  padding: 10px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="https://github.com">
          <img src="github.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Why Github?</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Enterprise</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Marketplace</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search GitHub">
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <a href="#">Sign In</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

---

Incidentally, the Github navigation you referenced has a somewhat more complex structure and uses nested flexboxes.

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In this case dont use Flex.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.navigation__left {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}

.navigation__right {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: right;
}

.navigation__left,
.navigation__right {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navigation__left img {
  height: 4vh;
}

.navigation__left__dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

.navigation__left:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.navigation__left:nth-child(even):hover .navigation__left__dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navigation__right:last-child a {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0.5vw 1vw 0.5vw 1vw;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

input {
  height: 3vh;
  width: 15vw;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3%;
  padding: 10px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="https://github.com">
          <img src="github.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Why Github?</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Enterprise</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Marketplace</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search GitHub">
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <a href="#">Sign In</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Very great! But how can I align vertically without flex?

Comment: you means vertical center?

Comment: Yep that's it!!

Comment: in this case i would suggest use 2 different ul that will help

Answer (score 1):

You can set  `display:flex` to `inline-block`

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.navigation__left {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}

.navigation__right {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: right;
}

.navigation__left,
.navigation__right {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navigation__left img {
  height: 4vh;
}

.navigation__left__dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

.navigation__left:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.navigation__left:nth-child(even):hover .navigation__left__dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navigation__right:last-child a {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0.5vw 1vw 0.5vw 1vw;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

input {
  height: 3vh;
  width: 15vw;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3%;
  padding: 10px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="https://github.com">
          <img src="github.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Why Github?</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Enterprise</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Marketplace</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__left">
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <ul class="navigation__left__dropdown">
          <li>Dropdown 1</li>
          <li>Dropdown 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search GitHub">
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <a href="#">Sign In</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__right">
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the display:flex property

```
.navigation {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```