# Align button groups some to the left and some to the right

Tags: html, css

How can I align button groups, 3 buttons to the left and another 3 buttons to the right with an input field in the middle in a div.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" name="textfield" value="">
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Before:
[before applying your answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk0W3.png)

[after applying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KyUl.png)

[This is how I want to arrange them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuXAN.png)

Comment: Are  you using Bootstrap? What CSS have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox solves your requirement. Learn more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.button-group{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" name="textfield" value="">
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.center{
  text-align: center;
}
.right{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <input type="text" name="textfield" value="">
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="button-group right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or do you mean like this?
Source: ([Making a flex item float right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182635/making-a-flex-item-float-right))

```css
.button-container{
  display: flex;
}
.right{
  margin-left: auto;
}
.center{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="button-group left">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-group right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <input type="text" name="textfield" value="">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I need three buttons to the right, three to the left, and the text field in the middle. I'm a beginner in HTML and CSS.

Comment: thank you for your help, please, look at the screenshots after applying your answer to my case. I need you help please